# Cannot open files in FileMaker Server 19(message: The host's capacity was exceeded)

Tags: filemaker

I am just starting out with FileMaker and have run into a problem with FileMaker Server 19. I have a client file that I have shared with the server which is showing up as expected in the FMS Admin console under the Databases tab. However, when I try to open it to make it active in FM Server, it won't open.

The only message I receive is that the host's capacity has been exceeded, which doesn't make sense since it is a fresh install and no clients have been hosted yet.

I have looked around online to try to find a solution but haven't found anything that works. Most solutions refer to the number of simultaneous clients permitted by FM Server.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a question about programming. Ask on one of the forums dedicated to the Filemaker platform.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure where to ask this question and there seemed to be other FM related questions on SO. I have posted it on the Server Fault forum, where I hope it's a better fit. Thanks againg for the input.

Comment: I doubt you will find FMS experts there, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Maybe not, but I thought it was worth a shot.

Comment: I repeat my suggestion to ask on one of the FM-specific forums.